# Intellij idea + maven + java (не загружаются зависимости)

Tags: maven

Суть проблемы:
Есть проект мавен, вот его `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CnBill</groupId>
    <artifactId>CnBill</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

И если создаю `WebDriver` - он его не подтягиват и любые зависимоти.
Пишет:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте **scope**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: спасибо, разобрался)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).